# Information about Evolutionary Art

Tags: evolutionary-algorithm

I have begun to do some research about Evolutionary Art algorithm. I read a lot of documents about it. But it seems not easy to understand.
The website http://picbreeder.com is a great example for this. But I don't need this in the beginning because it is too complex.
 Where can I find some ***simple code*** about this in Java? I think read code could help me much.
Thanks!!!

Comment: Google "genetic algorithm mona lisa"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Evolutionary Design by Computers" By David Bentley ([amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Evolutionary-Design-Computers-Peter-Bentley/dp/155860605X/)) has a couple of chapters on evolutionary art. However i dont think it includes any code / pseudocode. The canonical GA should do all you need, however the termination condition could be tricky as art is a subjective subject. (Not objective and therefore enumerable)

Hope this helps...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the EJC library might help you out, and it looks like a number of open source projects/tools come up if you Google for "java evolutionary computing."

I don't know how simple it is, and believe me it needs to be cleaned up a bit, but I have something that might get you started at https://github.com/murmux/Evo/tree/master/assignment2c  It doesn't deal with art, rather game theory, but you can use it under the terms of the GPLv3 if you'd like.  That uses Genetic Programming... I have another example using a more vanilla EA I might put up later.

Instead of evolving programs to play "Iterated Prisoner's Dilemma," you would evolve programs to generate an art work.  The fun part is coming up with a way to "score" an image for its fitness.  (Although Picbreeder seems to skip scoring by having you pick the mating pool directly...)

Answer (score 0):

Check this app: [EvoPic](http://www.mshams.ir/programs/evopic), its An evolutionary picture creator that uses Steady-State Genetic Algorithm, to produce evolutionary pictures by drawing uni-code characters in a picture box.

Example: [image]